# why does spinlock with std::memory_order_relaxed perform correctly?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, atomic, memory-barriers, spinlock

I implemented a spin-lock with C++11 atomic library:

```
class SpinLock {
  atomic_bool latch_;

  public:
  SpinLock() :latch_(false){
  }
  void lock() {
    while(tryLock() == false);
  }
  bool tryLock() {
    bool b = false;
    return latch_.compare_exchange_weak(b,true,std::memory_order_relaxed);
  }
  void unlock() {
    latch_.store(false,std::memory_order_relaxed);
  }
};
```

I tested the correctness by spawning multiple threads as follows:

```
static int z = 0;
static SpinLock spinLock;
static void safeIncrement(int run) {
  while(--run >= 0) {
    std::lock_guard<SpinLock> guard(spinLock);
    ++z;
  }
}

static void test(int nThreads =2) {
  std::vector<std::thread*> workers(nThreads);
  z = 0;
  for(auto& ptr : workers) ptr = new std::thread(safeIncrement,1<<20);
  for(auto ptr : workers) ptr->join();
  cout<<"after increment: " <<z << " out of " << (1<<20) * nThreads<<endl;
  for(auto ptr : workers) delete ptr;
}
int main() {

  test(4);

  return 0;

}
```

I am surprised the total at the end adds up as a correct value with relaxed order. By this article: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order, relaxed order means "there are no synchronization or ordering constraints", so the change from one thread is not meant to be visible from others, right? Why is it still correct?

(The test is run on Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3337U CPU @ 1.80GHz)

**EDIT:** (thanks to Maxim's comment) Updated the code: initializing data member in the SpinLock, and updating the test code.

Comment: Provide complete test source code.

Comment: There is no initialization of `SpinLock::latch_`, its initial value is indeterminate.

Comment: Is that *specifically* a C++11 question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++11 standard specifies the weakest guarantees for the atomic operations.  Not all hardware can match each weakest guarantee exactly, and so the compiler and library writer must sometimes "round up" to stronger operations.  For example, all atomic read-modify-write operations on x86 implicitly have `memory_order_acq_rel`.

Furthermore, specific implementations of a hardware architecture may have stronger guarantees than what the hardware manuals say.  For example, early Itaniums implemented memory_order_acq_rel semantics even for some hardware instructions that promised only memory_order_release.

Theoretically, it is possible for your code to fail on x86, because respecting memory ordering of atomic operations involves *both* the hardware and compiler.  An aggressive compiler could legally move the load of 'z' (and possibly the store too!) up over the `tryLock` operation that uses only `memory_order_release` ordering.

Comment: A fine point I left out is that "release" performs synchronization only when (dynamically) paired with an "acquire" on the *same* location.  Since you declared `spinLock` as static, and all operations on it are visible to the compiler, the compiler could observe that there are never matching "acquire" operations for `spinLock` and legally change all your operations on variable `spinLock` to `memory_order_relaxed`.

Comment: That Intel line of processors promises release every write (writes are never reordered) and acquire on every read (a read speculation is canceled if a conflicting write occurs) so of course an operation that is a read and a write has at least acq_rel semantic. It follows from the axioms.

Answer (score 1):

I see that at least GCC 6.3 at x86-64 generates same code for relaxed and for release/acquire. So, it's not surprising that results are same. So, to see the difference you may want more relaxed memory architecure than TSO that x86-64 provides. Probably, it might be ARM.

Comment: It is possible that `z` has expected value because it is declared as `std::atomic<int>`, or `run` is non-positive, or because there is only one thread.

Answer (score 0):

Using a relaxed ordering constraint on a mutex implementation is a recipe for disaster.
Mutexes are, by definition, intended to synchronize data between threads. The terms *acquire* and *release* are strongly associated with a mutex;
you *acquire* a mutex, change data protected by it and *release* the mutex so that the data becomes visible to another thread once it acquires the same mutex.

The article you are referring to states that for relaxed operations, "*there are no synchronization or ordering constraints*"... It applies to memory operations surrounding the mutex,
not the mutex itself. With relaxed ordering, data that is supposed to be protected by the mutex, may actually be modified concurrently by multiple threads (introducing a data race).

On a stronger ordered architecture such as `X86`, which has implicit acquire/release semantics, you will get away with this implementation (hence your tests succeed).
However, run it on an architecture that uses a weaker memory ordering such as `Power` or `ARMv7` and you are in trouble.

The orderings you suggest in the comments are correct.

Comment: Still, "memory operations surrounding the mutex" could involve the operations on the mutex itself, right?

Comment: @LeoLai  Operations on the mutex itself are atomic since they only modify the internal `atomic_bool` - that is what you get even with relaxed ordering.
However, "memory operations surrounding the mutex" are operations that come before or after the mutex (in program order).
Since a mutex is used to synchronize between threads it has to enforce ordering between memory operations before the 'unlock/release', and after the 'lock/acquire'.....

Comment: ..... An 'unlock/release' operation on a mutex _must_ prevent memory operations that precede it (in program order) from moving down across the mutex,
while a 'lock/acquire' operation _must_ prevent memory operations that follow it from moving up across the mutex.
These orderings are guaranteed by setting the acquire/release barriers on the atomic_bool operations in the mutex implementation.